# How can I make workflow task tables sortable in DSpace?

Tags: dspace

In DSpace XMLUI with a Mirage 2 theme, I would like the "tasks in the pool" and "tasks you own" tables on the submissions page to be sortable and filterable. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy differs slightly on whether the traditional DSpace workflow is used vs the configurable workflow.

The answers below are for DSpace 5; the changes may need to be slightly different for other DSpace versions.

**Unique IDs for task tables (traditional DSpace workflow only)**

The first issue to fix is that the two tables have the same ID. Change `dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/xmlworkflow/Submissions.java` to create different IDs for the two tables.

```
        // Tasks you own
-       Table table = workflow.addTable("workflow-tasks",ownedItems.size() + 2,5);
+       Table table = workflow.addTable("workflow-tasks-owned",ownedItems.size() + 2,5);    
        table.setHead(T_w_head2);
```

And likewise for Tasks in the pool further down in the same file.

**Fix table structure**

Add a few templates to that ensure the tables have `thead` / `tbody` / `tfoot` structure.

```xml
   <xsl:template match="dri:table[@n='workflow-tasks-pooled' or @n='workflow-tasks-owned']">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="dri:head"/>
           <div class="table-responsive">
                   <table>
                           <xsl:call-template name="standardAttributes">
                                   <xsl:with-param name="class">ds-table table table-striped table-hover</xsl:with-param>
                           </xsl:call-template>
                           <xsl:apply-templates select="dri:row[1]"/>
                           <tbody>
                                   <xsl:apply-templates select="dri:row[position()!=1 and position()!=last()]"/>
                           </tbody>
                           <xsl:apply-templates select="dri:row[last()]"/>
                   </table>
           </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="dri:table[@n='workflow-tasks-pooled' or @n='workflow-tasks-owned']/dri:row[@role='header']">
           <thead>
           <tr class="ds-table-header-row">
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="dri:cell"/>
           </tr>
           </thead>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="dri:table[@n='workflow-tasks-pooled' or @n='workflow-tasks-owned']/dri:row[last()]">
           <tfoot>
                   <tr>
                           <xsl:apply-templates select="dri:cell"/>
                   </tr>
           </tfoot>
   </xsl:template>
```

**Fix JavaScript/CSS paths**

The imports in `dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/styles/classic_mirage_color_scheme/_main.scss` aren't quite right. Fix them like so:

```
index bc58570..95444c7 100644
--- a/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/styles/classic_mirage_color_scheme/_main.scss
+++ b/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/styles/classic_mirage_color_scheme/_main.scss
@@ -31,8 +31,8 @@
 @import "classic_mirage_color_scheme/vocabulary-support";

 @import "classic_mirage_color_scheme/jquery_ui";
-@import "classic_mirage_color_scheme/dataTables.bootstrap";
+//@import "classic_mirage_color_scheme/dataTables.bootstrap";
 @import "shared/dspace-bootstrap-tweaks";
 @import "../vendor/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css";
-@import "../vendor/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css";
+@import "../vendor/datatables/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css";
 @import "style";
```

**Activate datatables functionality**

Then, activate the [datatables](https://datatables.net/) functionality by adding the following to `theme.js`. Swap in configuration that works for you -- the changes below will

- enable pagination and filtering when there are at least 5 items in the table;
- allow sorting by all columns except the first (which contains checkboxes);
- disable sorting by default; and
- put in some language tweaks.

**You will need to adjust the IDs if you're using the traditional workflow.**

```js
$(function() {
var poolTable = $('#aspect_xmlworkflow_Submissions_table_workflow-tasks-pooled');
poolTable.DataTable({
    "paging": poolTable.find("tbody tr").size() >= 5,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "info": false,
    "searching": poolTable.find("tbody tr").size() >= 5,
    "columnDefs": [
        { targets: 0, orderable: false, searchable: false }
    ],
    "order": [],
    "oLanguage" : {
        "sSearch": "Filter tasks:"
    }
});
poolTable.closest(".dataTables_wrapper").before("<p class='help'>Click on a column header to sort the table by that column.</p>");

var ownedTable = $('#aspect_xmlworkflow_Submissions_table_workflow-tasks-owned');
ownedTable.DataTable({
    "paging": ownedTable.find("tbody tr").size() >= 5,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "info": false,
    "searching": ownedTable.find("tbody tr").size() >= 5,
    "columnDefs": [
        { targets: 0, orderable: false, searchable: false }
    ],
    "order": []
});
ownedTable.closest(".dataTables_wrapper").before("<p class='help'>Click on a column header to sort the table by that column.</p>");
});
```